# keeps coming up with invalid syntax error for my elif statement

Tags: python

**before i was repeating the similar codes along the print menu within each option selection but i changed it from while to if and elif but doesn't work? it keeps coming up with syntax error**

```
option = 0

while option !=4:

    # Prints the menu to the screen
        print("*** Menu *** \n")
        print("1. Encrypt string")
        print("2. Decrypt string")
        print("3. Brute force decryption")
        print("4. Quit \n")

# Prompts the user
option = int(input("What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? "))

# input error

if option ==1:
#if the user's selection equals 1


            # Prints to the screen the chosen option and prompts the user to input
            print("In command 1 - encrypt string \n")
            string = input("Please enter string to encrypt: ")
            offsetvalue = int(input("Please enter positive offset value: "))
            print("")

# input error
while offsetvalue > 26 or offsetvalue < 1:
    offsetvalue = int(input("Please enter a positive offset value between 1 - 26: "))

    # Assigns the 'Encryption' variable
    # letter which is encrypted

    Encryption = ""

# Loops the input in variable 'code' for each letter
for letter in string:
    # Converts each letter in 'code' to an ASCII value
    # and adds the positive offset value
    encryption_num = ord(letter)
    encryption_num += offsetvalue

# Loops the ASCII value
if encryption_num > 126:
        encryption_num -= 94
        # adds it to the total string
        encryption_num = chr(encryption_num)
        Encryption += encryption_num
        # encrypted string to the screen
        print("\nEncrypted string:")
        print(Encryption)

elif option == 2:

        # prompts the user to input
        print("In command 2 - decrypt string \n")
        string = input("Please enter string to decrypt: ")
        offsetvalue = int(input("Please enter negative offset value: "))
        print("")

# input error

while offsetvalue < -26 or offsetvalue > -1:
    offsetvalue = int(input("Please enter negative offset value between -1 - -26: "))

# Assigns the 'Decryption' variable
# letter which is decrypted
    Decryption = ""

# Loops the input in variable 'string'

for letter in string:
    # adds variable 'string' to an ASCII value
    # adds negative offset value
    decryption_num = ord(letter)
    decryption_num += offsetvalue
    # Loops the ASCII value to beginning if True
    if decryption_num < 32:
            decryption_num += 94
            # Converts the letter back into a string and adds it to the total string
            decryption_num = chr(decryption_num)
            Decryption += decryption_num
            # Prints the entire decrypted string to the screen
            print("\nDecrypted string:")
            print(Decryption)
```

**This is where it highlights the error with the elif statement not sure why? it comes up with an invalid message in python.**

```
elif option == 3:
     print("in command 3 -brute force \n")
     string = input("please enter string to decrypt: ")
     offsetvalue = -0
     while offsetvalue != -26:
     decryption_num = 0
     Decryption = ""
while Decryption < len(letter):
      c = ord(string[decryption_num]) + offsetvalue
      if c < 0:
      c += 128
      decryption_num = chr(c)
      Decryption += decryption_str
      decryption_num += 1
      offsetvalue -= 1
      print ("\noffset", offsetvalue, "=Decrypted string:", Decryption)

    # Prompts the user for their selection
    option = int(input("What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? "))

#input error
elif option == 4:
        print ("\nGoodbye")
```

Comment: Please show the complete error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an `elif` after a `while` or a `for`.  `elif` can only come after `if` or another `elif`.  Did you mean for that `while` to be indented under the previous `if`?

Your code has other problems.  You seem to be comparing a string against a number (`Decryption < len(letter)`).

You have something like this:

```
if option == 2:
    # stuff

while something:
    # stuff

elif option == 3:
    # stuff
```

You can't do that.  You may have meant this:

```
if option == 2:
    # stuff

    while something:
        # stuff

elif option == 3:
    # stuff
```

However, I can't tell you exactly what to change because I don't know precisely what you want your code to do.  I would suggest you read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with the basics of Python.

Comment: The `elif` comes after a `for`, but yes, this is the problem, *roughly*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It looks like that's true if he meant his second code snippet to follow immediately after the first.  But also at the very end he has an `elif` after `while`.

Comment: Indeed, that'd be another location that there'd be the same error.

Comment: i am new to programming can you show me the parts to change so i can understand please @BrenBarn

Comment: @legend: I gave some more info in my edited answer, but I can't tell exactly what you wanted to do.  My advice is to read a Python tutorial and learn the basics of Python.